# Sitecore context in HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, ihttpmodule

I created simple `HttpModule`, all what I need is just get is valid `Sitecore.Context` inside but during processing I see that my `Sitecore.Context` is some kind of default.

I can get Sitecore user that log in to Sitecore, etc.
How to fix it ?

Comment: When does the HttpModule run?  What triggers it?

Comment: I need to process Authenticated event

Comment: Does the HttpModule run when you access a Sitecore Item via the Url?

Comment: Yes it does. and I can debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a Sitecore Context, but it is null or set to the wrong site or language.
You can change the context like this:

```
// switch to the preferred site    
Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("yourSiteName");

// set the preferred database
Sitecore.Context.Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

// set the preferred language
Language language =  Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("en");
Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage = (language, false);
```

You probably also want to switch back to the original settings after your processing is done. So it is wise to "save" the original settings in a variable so you can change them back afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at John West's posts on Sitecore pipelines for some background on how the context is being established.

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Pipelines-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

and

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/Important-Pipelines-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

The following blog post on creating and running custom pipelines should give you an idea how to implement your own pipeline.

http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/creating-and-running-custom-pipelines-in-sitecore/